# what is the correct transaltion in c of the createlist function declaration from Data structures Book by Richard F. Gilberg

Tags: c

Here is the function

```c
*/ 
LIST* createList   (int (*compare) (void* argu1, void* argu2)) {      
//Local Definitions  

LIST* list; 
//Statements  
list = (LIST*) malloc (sizeof (LIST)); if (list) 
 {  
list->head = NULL;  
list->pos = NULL; 
 list->rear = NULL; 
 list->count = 0; 
 list->compare = compare;  } // if  
 return list; 
} // createList
```

LIST* createList   (int (* compare) (void* argu1, void* argu2))
My attempt Createlist is a function expecting parameter  (compare is a pointer to function expecting generic pointers and returning integer    )returning * List

Comment: It is unclear what is the question.

Comment: Please check now I have added the code for the function .I am not able to understand the declaration properly of the createlist.

Answer (score 1):

`createList` is a function with one function pointer parameter and returning a pointer to `LIST`.

The type of the parameter is "**pointer to function taking (void*, void*) parameters and returning int**"

Presumably you have a function somewhere like:

```
int my_comp(void* argu1, void* argu2) // this matches the type of the createList parameter
{
    // do something to compare *argu1 and *argu2
    return 0; // or some other integer value
}
```

Then you call `createList`, passing it a pointer to `my_comp`:

```
LIST* my_list = createList(my_comp); // this passes the address of my_comp to createList
```